# .htaccess error document using html fragment - not working, but why?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, fragment, error-code

Can anyone help me with this?

I am trying to direct error codes to error.html#401 etc.

As an example, when you go to http://www.interimspaces.co.uk and click the link under email invitation, if you cancel twice you get the basic page but without text,

when you should get http://interimspaces.co.uk/error.html#401

I have tried putting the .htaccess file top level directory, then in interimspaces.co.uk/pitch, but i'm getting the same problem.

the code reads:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html#401
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html#404
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html#500
```

any help appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is the start of a comment in apache files, so you need to wrap it in quotes:

```
ErrorDocument 401 "/error.html#401"
```

Comment: argh - doesn't look like that did the job unfortunately

Comment: @annoyingnewbie try using the full URL such as `ErrorDocument 401 "http://example.com/error.html#401"`

Comment: still no joy - tried the full expression. can't imagine what i'm doing wrong

Comment: using this formatting *ErrorDocument 404 /error.html#404* it is showing the html but minus the html fragments... which is really odd. apache might have an issue parsing the fragments, but there must be a way to overcome this... ?

Comment: @annoyingnewbie shouldn't it be `ErrorDocument 404 "http://interimspaces.co.uk/error.html#404"`?

Comment: i did try that - and a variety of other possible solutions - unfortunately nothing worked. when i included the full address and encapsulated it in quotes, i got the standard apache response instead of my custom one, which means it was totally overlooked